# Doubts in Sorting algorithm-Pancake flipping.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sorting

Here, is the solution pdf for the pancake sorting problem.

[http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~ustcsh/py2016/data/GP79.pdf](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eustcsh/py2016/data/GP79.pdf)

In the fifth page, the para with the start,"where xi is multiplied by the number of flippings involved....." till the end of the table 2 has been difficult for me to understand.

I cant seem to understand why the adjacencies created out of the actions *X31,X32,X33,X34* are *2,3,3,3* respectively.

Can anyone please explain how this is possible in an easy way?

Also, please explain the row of ***'increase in number of blocks'*** as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a lot to work through, so I am not sure I can immediately help, but notice: (a) Is that Bill Gates who is one of the authors of the article? (b) Look up https://oeis.org/A058986 , the upper bound seems to have got improved since 1978; (c) It seems it's been covered by Numberphile: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3drS_8BpU0

Comment: @StinkingBishopYes!Bill gates!